# Android service onCreate is called multiple times without calling onDestroy

Tags: android, service, oncreate, ondestroy

In my app, I use a service to communicate with our server. The Service spawns several message queue threads to deal with tasks with different priorities.

This model has been used for about one year without big issues. However, recently, I found some time the `onCreate` of my service class are called multiple times. `onDestroy` is never called between two `onCreate` calls. Therefore, I did not get chance to kill existing threads. Once this behavior happens, the service has duplicate threads inside.

The only thing I have changed is to run the service as foreground service is a user signs in the app. I am wondering whether foreground service cause the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: same problem call `stopSelf()` service then after automatically call `onCreate()`
multiple time call `onCreate()` method

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem when my service used the same process with activities(default). but no more problems when I made my service use another process. I edited my AndroidManifest.xml like below... (added **android:process** attribute)

```
<service android:name="kr.co.pkbio.binoo.CacheFileManagerService" android:process=":kr.co.pkbio.binoo.service"/>
<service android:name="kr.co.pkbio.binoo.ActivityStackManagerService" android:process=":kr.co.pkbio.binoo.service"/>
```

see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html for information.

Comment: I have a service that runs in a different process but still has this problem occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem when I was dealing with a bluetooth service (the problem occurred during the development). When I disconnected my device and killed the ADB it didn't happen again and onCreate was called only once. I assume it is some bug because it happens from time to time. But maybe you have a slightly different problem...

Answer (score 0):

This might become useful to someone. 
I had this same issue when storing a map through a bundle in a onSaveInstanceState method in one of my activities. I believe because the map contained references to objects that were being used in other parts of the app (one of them was my service) every time I left said activity, my service would start all over again.

I'm guessing this is android OS shenanigans.

Comment: How did you solve this? I'm having the same problem. When I leave the main app, my service gets recreated.